# Problem with deploying app on a server (mismatched java versions)

Tags: java, maven

I have java 8 installed on my computer, on the server there is a java 1.6.0_32 installed. So in my pom file I'm using

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

to say that I want to compile it in java 6. Also in my project Settings I can see that I'm using java 6 both for every module and for the whole project. But, when I try to deploy the app on the server I got error

```
Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

so it looks like the maven compiler ignores my 1.6 configuration.... I don't have any idea what should I do more. I'm using intelij ultimate edition, btw.
My dependencies in pom file are:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.15</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-tiles-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-jasperreports-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-jasperreports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jasypt/jasypt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
            <artifactId>DynamicJasper-core-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ar.com.fdvs/DynamicJasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
            <artifactId>DynamicJasper</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.dynamicreports/dynamicreports-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dans</groupId>
            <artifactId>dans-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/javax.faces-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opensymphony/xwork -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opensymphony</groupId>
            <artifactId>xwork</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: How are you building the artifact you're deploying? You're mentioning both maven and Intellij; do you use `mvn package` and then deploying whatever is created in target/?

Comment: I'm using mvn clean package. I'm building a .war and then deploying whole war on the jboss server

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to some `<dependency>` in your POM.

Java 6 is very old, so most dependencies nowadays will require a newer version of Java.

Comment: I thought so too, so I'm using the same dependency version as was used earlier as .jar libs. I'm moving old project to the maven.

Comment: For example `httpclient` in version 4.5.13 is from 2020. I doubt that they support Java 6.

Comment: ok an is there any way to check the version of java that it uses? in mvnrepository I can't find any info about that

Comment: If you had them as jars before and are now letting maven download them, it's likely that even if the version numbers are the same, the builds are newer and use new bytecode versions. In those cases, the best solution may be to include the jars directly with `<systempath>`

Comment: @mario the [enforce plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) can be used to at least point you to the dependencies that have the wrong bytecode version.

Comment: Systempath causes trouble. I would avoid that. One should think about updating Java, at least to Java 8.

Comment: yes, I aggre @JFabianMeier, but unfortunately I heard we can't update Java to 8, maybe I will get permission to upgrade to 7, but not sure yet

Comment: What stops you from using Java 8?

Comment: the fact that the app is used by some clients, and the server which it uses is on Java 6. From what I heard uprgrading the server is impossible for some reasons connected with other projects

Comment: @OhleC Funny fact is that when I'm using enforcer with requiredJAvaVersion 1.6.0 it says everyting is fine after enrorcer:enforce command

Comment: I would have a look for dependencies from 2012 or before. They are probably build with Java 6 or less.